# Count of Availability Zones in Each region in Azure for EventGrid , Event Hub

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-eventhub, azure-eventgrid, availability-zone

Any az cli command in general to get to know count (1?2?3?) of availability zones in a particular region of Azure?
I am trying to get these details for EventGrid and event hub specifically..

Comment: Can you provide the code what you have tried so far? @ABC DEF

Answer (score 1):

> Count of Availability Zones in Each region:

*To list out the locations and availability zones, use below CLI command.*

```bash
az account list-locations -o table
```

[image]

*To list out the locations and availability zones in `eastUS` region, use below CLI command.*

```bash
az account list-locations -o table --query "[?name=='eastus']"
```

[image]

*To count the number of availability zones, use* `length([])` *function as shown.*

```bash
az account list-locations -o table --query "length([])"
```

[image]

*To retrieve availability zones and their counts for any specific resources, use below CLI commands: (Eg: EventHub)*

```bash
az eventhubs eventhub list --resource-group <resourcegroup>  --namespace-name <Namespace> --query "[?contains('Location', 'WestUS')]" -o table
az resource list --resource-group <resourcegroup> --name <resourceName> --resource-type Microsoft.EventGrid/domains --query "length([])"
```